# Which Star Trek Original Series episode has a Starfleet Captain leading an alien village?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

The details I remember are too vague to Google... apparently.

The story surrounds the crew of the Enterprise discovering that the leader of the village where they're visiting (I forget why) is actually a Starfleet Captain who has abandoned his command and is aiding the aboriginals in violation of the Prime Directive.

I'm pretty sure it's not *Private Little War*, nor *A Taste of Armageddon*, but I'm open to being convinced.

I don't remember any names or other specific details, only that (spoiler for *Star Trek Beyond*):

> ...it's essentially the same bad guy as in *Star Trek Beyond*.

I'll update with any details I remember...

Comment: Are you sure it was a TV show? What you're describing is an almost perfect description of the Trek prequel comic [Countdown to Darkness](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Countdown_to_Darkness)

Comment: Probably not because he wasn't a captain, and he runs the entire planet rather than a village, but there's also [Patterns of Force](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Patterns_of_Force). Turns out, TOS did this a lot.

Comment: Is it Patterns of Force? Were the natives Nazis?

Comment: @Countdown, Nope, I've never read any of the comics ;-) Yeah, they did this a lot... a whole lot...

Comment: homage/ripoff : http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_Commandment

Comment: Voyager has an episode where some Ferengi found their way through a wormhole into the Delta Quadrant and set themselves up as messiahs (mainly on the basis of replicator technology) but that's perhaps not the one you mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be ["The Omega Glory"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Omega_Glory_(episode)):

> **Kirk:** Captain's log, supplemental. The *Enterprise* has left the *Exeter* and has moved into close planet orbit. Although it appears the infection may strand us here the rest of our lives, I face an even more difficult problem – a growing belief that Captain Tracey has been interfering with the evolution of life on this planet.
>
> <sup>*Star Trek* Season 2 Episode 25: "The Omega Glory"</sup>

The episode finds the *Enterprise* discovering an abandoned starship, the *Exeter*, in orbit around a planet, nearly the entire crew having been killed by an unknown alien disease.

The lone survivor is the ship's captain, Captain Tracey, who is living on the planet<sup>1</sup> among the "Kohms", one of two technologically-primitive indigenous tribes. Having gone slightly nutty as a result of being the only survivor of his crew, Captain Tracey has decided to use his advanced Starfleet technology to assist the Kohms against their rival tribe, the Yangs.

---

<sup>1</sup> Because for some reason, staying on this one planet prevents the disease from spreading. It's *Star Trek*, what do you want?

Comment: This is the one! Thanks!

Comment: originally one of the three scripts Roddenberry wanted to film for the pilot - thank goodness that didn't happen

Answer (score 3):

Could this be "[TOS: The Paradise Syndrome](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Paradise_Syndrome_(episode))"?

> Trapped on a planet whose inhabitants are descended from Northwestern
>   American Indians, **Kirk loses his memory and is proclaimed a God** while
>   the crippled Enterprise races back to the planet before it is
>   destroyed by an asteroid.

Comment: Close, but the Starfleet Officer was someone other than Kirk.

Comment: That's "Lord Garth!"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the episode you are looking for is 
'Whom Gods Destroy' centering on an ex Starfleet captain (Captain Garth) who has taken control of a mental institution and holds Kirk and Spock prisoners.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Whom_Gods_Destroy_(episode)